# Registration id is not generating for sending push notification using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, registration, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
//Here is my code of FIREBASEINSTANCEIDSERVICE
```

//reg_id is not generating
//without id i am not able to send notifications. app is running without any errors.
//I am not getting why it is happening, i am beginner, that is why i m not getting. please resolve this.

```
package com.fication.noti.mynotification.service;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.fication.noti.mynotification.app.Config;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

/**
 * Created by lenovo on 05/11/2016.
 */
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG =           MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        super.onTokenRefresh();
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
      //  Log.d(TAG,"Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // Saving reg id to shared preferences
        storeRegIdInPref(refreshedToken);

        // sending reg id to your server
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);

        // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress   indicator can be hidden.
        Intent registrationComplete = new  Intent(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
        registrationComplete.putExtra("token", refreshedToken);
      LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
    } 

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(final String token) {
        // sending gcm token to server
        Log.e(TAG, "sendRegistrationToServer: " + token);
    }

    private void storeRegIdInPref(String token) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString("regId", token);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you initialized Firebase in your Application class?

`FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);`

Comment: Thanks and i apologise for late response. I was able to solve it by Initialising Firebase.